# Can someone fulfill his Shabbat meal obligation through his family if they eat a k'betza and he eats just a bit?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shiurim-measurements, choleh-sick, challah-shabbat-bread

Suppose someone for health reasons can't eat a full k'betza of bread but can eat a crumb.

He wants to l'chatchila (or bedi'eved) fulfil the standard Shabbat obligation of seuda and lechem mishna for himself.

**Does this get fulfilled if he makes the bracha and he only eats a small bite (or none at all?), so long as it is certain the others at the table will eat a kebetza between them?**

I base this question on an etza I once heard about what to do if you go to someone's house who doesn't drink half a revi'it of wine by kiddush, you can rely on the fact that between everyone, a revi'it will be drunk.

As a bonus/related questions:

- Can he/should he wash? With bracha?
- He can say birchat hamazon for his family (due to heter because people will forget; see SH O'H 213:1, Magen Avraham s'k 4, Taz s'k 1, MB s'k 9, I believe the minimum amount for the father in this case might be a kezayit based on Yalkut Yosef 186:4, although in other places no amount is specified, see 213), so in this situation, should he strive to do so?
- Do these add to / are they ideal / incumbent for his own mitzva for the day?

Maybe another way to phrase this last bit, as I am clearly struggling, is, should he feel disappointed that he missed out on something important for Shabbat, if he didn't get to wash or bentch?

Comment: "He can say birchat hamazon for his family" Can you source this? Usually one can only say birkat hamazon for others through a zimmun or if they are unable to recite it themselves.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes I'll find the source for that and add it later. It might just be a heter, in which case I'll update the wording accordingly

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard a shiur which mentioned this recently and it is a Sephardi thing and not done by Ashkenazim

Comment: I don't think any of this works, but you need to ask a rabbi. Health questions in general are very tricky and need a competent rav.

Comment: 213:1 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%90 ??

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, those are the sources for the heter, but I think you are confused by the last 213, which is referring to Yalkut Yosef Shome'a Ka'one